# How does JavaScript array.reverse() works under the hood?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

How can I  make a reversed copy of an array using `.reverse()`? I can't wrap my head around this.

This is my function:

```
function flipArray(inputArray){
let origArray = inputArray;
let flippedArray = origArray.reverse();

console.log(inputArray);
console.log(origArray);
console.log(flippedArray);
}

flipArray([1,2,3]);
```

I would expect this...

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

or this...

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

but this is what I get...

```
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Why does even inputArray get reversed? Is there another way to do this apart from a `for` loop?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse - The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object **in place**, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/86967) for more information about how to make a separate copy of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reverse` reverse the array *in-place*. It modifies the original array and returns a reference to it. In order to create copies of the original array before it is reversed, you could use `Array.prototype.slice`, for example:

```
function flipArray(inputArray){

    let origArray = inputArray.slice(0);
    let flippedArray = inputArray.slice(0).reverse();

    console.log(inputArray);
    console.log(origArray);
    console.log(flippedArray);
}
```

`flipArray([1,2,3])` now produces

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
[3,2,1]
```